# How to optimize my query? Exporting Wordpress posts with category and tag list

Tags: mysql, wordpress, query-optimization

I wrote query for export posts.

```
SELECT

post_name,
post_content,

Categories, 
Tags 

FROM

-- posts
    wp_posts as p

-- categories
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            object_id as cat_obj_id, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(cat_term.name) as Categories

        FROM
            wp_term_relationships AS cat_r 
            JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS cat_tax 
                ON cat_r.term_taxonomy_id = cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id
            JOIN wp_terms AS cat_term 
                ON cat_tax.term_id = cat_term.term_id

        WHERE cat_tax.taxonomy="category"
        GROUP by object_id) 
    as c

    ON p.id = c.cat_obj_id

-- tags
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            object_id as tag_obj_id, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(tag_term.name) as Tags

        FROM
            wp_term_relationships AS tag_r 
            JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tag_tax 
                ON tag_r.term_taxonomy_id = tag_tax.term_taxonomy_id
            JOIN wp_terms AS tag_term 
                ON tag_tax.term_id = tag_term.term_id

        WHERE tag_tax.taxonomy="post_tag"
        GROUP by object_id) 
    as t

    ON p.id = t.tag_obj_id
```

Table schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_term_taxonomy` (
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `taxonomy` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` longtext NOT NULL,
  `parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_taxonomy_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `term_id_taxonomy` (`term_id`,`taxonomy`),
  KEY `taxonomy` (`taxonomy`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `wp_term_relationships` (
  `object_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_taxonomy_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `term_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
  KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `wp_terms` (
  `term_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `slug` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `term_group` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`term_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

EXPLAIN:
[image]

Running this query on 1000 posts database takes 72 seconds (execute under 1 sec, fetching takes forever). Is there any way to make it faster, without temporary tables to store categories and tags?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.

Comment: Are any of these tables indexed?  You've shown no index definitions.

Comment: There are indexes on all joins and on `taxonomy` field, which is in `WHERE` clause in subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered, that my big query runs horribly slow when there are no records on one of subqueries, that are `LEFT JOIN`'ed.

To workaround this - I created temporary tables from subqueries and I replaced subqueries with these temporary tables.

Here is my SQL.

```
-- 1.1. Creating table for post categories
create table if not exists temp_categories
(
    ID bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Categories text not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


-- 1.2. Filling table temp_categories
INSERT INTO temp_categories(ID, Categories)
SELECT 
    'object_id' AS ID, -- post ID
    GROUP_CONCAT(cat_term.name ORDER BY cat_term.name) AS Categories -- comma separated category list
FROM
    wp_term_relationships AS cat_r 
    JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS cat_tax 
        ON cat_r.term_taxonomy_id = cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN wp_terms AS cat_term 
        ON cat_tax.term_id = cat_term.term_id
WHERE cat_tax.taxonomy="category"
GROUP by object_id;

-- 2.1. Creating table for post tags
create table temp_tags
(
    ID bigint not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Tags text not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;


-- 2.2. Filling table temp_tags

INSERT INTO exp_tagi(ID, Tagi)
SELECT 
    object_id AS ID, --post ID
    GROUP_CONCAT(tag_term.name ORDER BY tag_term.name) AS Tags -- comma separated tag list
        FROM
    wp_term_relationships AS tag_r 
    JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tag_tax 
        ON tag_r.term_taxonomy_id = tag_tax.term_taxonomy_id
    JOIN wp_terms AS tag_term 
        ON tag_tax.term_id = tag_term.term_id

WHERE tag_tax.taxonomy="post_tag"
GROUP by object_id;

-- 3. Exporting posts

SELECT
    p.id AS id,
    p.post_title AS Title,
    p.post_content AS Content,
    k.Categories AS Categories,
    t.Tags AS Tags,
    IF(p.post_status = 'publish', 1, 0) AS Published
FROM 
    wp_posts p
    left join temp_categories k 
        on p.id = k.id
    left join temp_tags t 
        on p.id = t.id
WHERE post_status in('publish', 'draft')
ORDER BY id;

-- 4. Deleting temporary tables
DROP TABLE temp_categories;
DROP TABLE temp_tags;
```

I could use `TEMPORARY` tables (no need for delete, they disappear when MySQL session ends), but I didnt because my PHP app ends MySQL session after each query.